# Manage multiple ports with Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, http, port, uri

I already switched my default port from 8080 to 80, but here's a problem: I need to also be able to manage port 8000, too. 
Current ports are: 8080, 80. How do I map a new port (8000) to a new webapp?

Answer (score 3):

You can setup Tomcat so that it will listen on multiple ports, without having to setup 2 instances, simply edit the `conf/server.xml` configuration file and add a new connector for the port you want. For example if you have a connector like that:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
       connectionTimeout="20000" 
       redirectPort="8443" 
       URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Add this to that file as well:

```
<Connector port="8000" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
       connectionTimeout="20000" 
       redirectPort="8443" 
       URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Make sure it's redirected to the appropriate location.

#### References

- [Running Tomcat server on two different ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231052/running-tomcat-server-on-two-different-ports)

Answer (score 2):

Create separate Service entries for each app and specify Connectors in there with different ports.

This has been addressed:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366843/how-to-deploy-mutiple-web-application-in-tomcat-which-will-run-on-different-port

Answer (score 0):

You run Tomcat twice, one with port 80 and once with port 8000 config, each with their own web app.

Comment: That's unnecessary overhead.  You don't need multiple instances.